# How to use hyperlink in JSP and Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to use hyperlink in my JSP page. currently I am new in Spring and JSP.
My hyperlink in JSP page is

```
<td><i align="center" style="margin-left: 183px;">
    <a href="/SpringMVC/Login.html"><u>Have a account</u></a>
</i></td>
```

And my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/SpringMVC/Login.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginForm(){
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("LoginPage");
        return model;
    }
```

When I click the hyperlink then it should open `LoginPage.jsp`.

Comment: What's the problem than?

Comment: Can some help to solve my problem?

Comment: You probably need to search for Spring controller tutorial. We cannot tell what is wrong cause we don't see Your context file (xml? annotations?).

Perhaps You didn't set mvc:annotation-driven in Your context, perhaps You didnt set mapping for Your controller, perhaps Your class is not annotated as Controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
var contextPath = /*[[@{/}]]*/
<a href=contextPath+"/SpringMVC/Login.html"><u>Have a account</u></a>
```

You should use context path / root path before the URL, because on the web there will become different URL as compared to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

add jstl taglib jar in your classpath and add this on jsp before html declaration.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

then do this in body.

```
<td><i align="center" style="margin-left: 183px;">
    <a href="<c:url value="/SpringMVC/Login.html"/>"><u>Have a account</u></a>
</i></td>
```